# Read all rows from excel (.xls) and then insert into database (PHP)

Tags: php, database, excel

Can anyone provides me the step or whole code to read data from excel file (.xls) and then insert that records to database?

Thank in advance,

Comment: if it is a one off, save as csv then use fgetcsv then insert into db

Comment: or use [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), but please try something before posting

Comment: export as csv is a lot easier, or use [PHPexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library. See [documentation examples](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/downloads/get/688496).

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

```
/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';
echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
var_dump($sheetData);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, if you must use PHP:

1. Use a library like [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) which will read the native XLS format.  Your success rate depends on how good the library is with deciphering the XLS format.
2. Convert *each sheet* into a plain text format (like a CSV file). These can be read easily in PHP using [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv).

If you just want to get data in Excel into MySQL, there is [MySQL for Excel](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/), an Excel plugin from the developers of MySQL.